# Are internet connection passwords available from some location in /home?

Tags: internet, network-manager

I keep /home on a separate partition. I upgrade by performing a fresh install. I assume that my internet connection passwords, like most of my other settings, will be stored somewhere in /home and so will be preserved.

But, no, they're saved in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections, so a fresh install wipes them out.

Are they somehow retrievable from some location in /home?

Thank you.

Comment: The beauty of fresh install is that all the old system-wide settings are gone. Unless you copied them in `/home` there is no way to get them back.

Answer (score 1):

Your Internet connection login/password, etc, are stored in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/... So, if you did a fresh install (rather than an upgrade) then you wiped those files out.

Did you copy them out to your /home/yourUserName/someplace? If not, then those are permanently gone. You will have to create them anew.

Bottomline: I don't think there's any way to (easily) recover that info now.